# Clean spark cache data

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I used *cache()* and *persist()* on *DataFrame* througout my application. And I want to know do I need to invoke *unpersist()* on each dataframe that I have cached to free up all memory and disk which have been occupied when my program is ending? Will spark automatically clean up those occupation?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Once spark context is stopped, memory will get free by itself. 
If you want to free the memory before stopping the context, in that case you have to invoke `unpersist`.

Comment: The data cached on disk will be removed like the one in memory when spark context end. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, the data from the disk will get erased as soon as the spark context gets stopped.